# CSS Two Columns of Lists - responsive merge into one column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two lists that I'm floating into two columns. I want to make it so on small screens, the items become one column, BUT I'd like to alternate the items.

```
<div>
    <ul class="left">
        <li>Item A</li>
        <li>Item B</li>
        <li>Item C</li>
        <li>Item D</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the result should look like this on small screens.

```
Item A
Item 1
Item B
Item 2
Item C
Item 3
Item D
Item 4
```

Here is my starting jsfiddle. Should I instead make one list with `li` `width` set to `50%`? I wanted to see if this was possible while keeping the HTML markup the way it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/aAhX9/

Comment: How much are the lists big?

Comment: @JoshC That's what I was thinking about.

Comment: Only 5 items. I think I'd merge the lists before making a third for mobile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to do this (outside of some very laborious positioning) is to combine the elements into a single list, giving each `li` a class-name and styling them appropriately:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="left">Item A</li>
        <li class="right">Item 1</li>
        <li class="left">Item B</li>
        <li class="right">Item 2</li>
        <li class="left">Item C</li>
        <li class="right">Item 3</li>
        <li class="left">Item D</li>
        <li class="right">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 50%;
}

li.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

li.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: #00f;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aAhX9/2/).

As noted by Hashem, in the comments below, it would be possible to use the `:nth-child()` selector, rather than class-names, to style the various `li` elements left, or right:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    background-color: #00f;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aAhX9/9/).

Comment: Brilliant @David. great job.

Comment: It's been a cause of much lament, between my parents, that I've yet to discover *what* the box *is*; let alone *where*... ;)

Comment: Also using `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` could be an option.

Comment: @Hashem: that's a very good point; edited it into the answer, thanks!

Comment: @HashemQolami `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/aAhX9/8/ would work but then you'd limit your desktop browser compatibility.

Comment: @Vector And how many browsers support [CSS3 media query](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)? 99.9% of browsers support media query, will support [`nth-child`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) selector as well.

Comment: The media query only needs to be supported by mobile browsers in the original example as the `li` were targeted by class, therefore a desktop could float them without a problem. The `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` option will not get floated by non-modern browsers and remain as a single list.

Comment: @Apptracker, very true. The second option would remain as a single list in an old browser. the first option is best. Supports desktops where needed and mobiles where needed. It would appear some people are confused by this concept

Comment: @HashemQolami the desktop doesn't need to support the media query in this example!. The first example would work on an iphone and ie7, the second one wouldn't.

Comment: @Vector But iOS since v3.2 to 7.0 support [`:nth-child()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). and does IE7 support media query itself? If so, fork the correspond page from caniuse.com and send a pull request.

Comment: Okay, one merged list seems like the best responsive solution. And it doesn't really hurt the semantics of the list items in my case so I'll do this

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with two `ul`. However, you can put two `span` in each `li`.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="left">Item A</span><span class="right">Item 1</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">Item B</span><span class="right">Item 2</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">Item C</span><span class="right">Item 3</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">Item D</span><span class="right">Item 4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

span{
    width: 50%;
}


.left {
    float: left;
    background:blue;
}


.right {
    float: right;
    background:Red;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        display:blocK;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aAhX9/5/)

Comment: It works visualy, but from a semantic point of view this is not consistant